# Modifying Tickets block in Events Calendar in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to add a 'Virtual Event URL' text box to the Events Calendar plugin. Where do I find the php / template files for this on the server?

[Screen shot of Event Calendar Add Event page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAuy2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the template for that specific plugin, but you can find it by installing the [query monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin, and then while looking at one of the events a menu will appear in the admin bar that will contain the name of the template.

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful! It was like a needle in a haystack looking for templates.